# Change JSON Keys in Nested JSON in SQL Table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sqlite, parsing

I have a table with column called tableJson which contains information of the following type:

```
[ 
  {
    "type": "TABLE",
    "content": {
                 "rows": 
                        [{"Date": "2021-09-28","Monthly return": "1.44%"},
                         {"Date": "2021-11-24", "Yearly return": "0.62%"},
                         {"Date": "2021-12-03", "Monthly return": "8.57%"},
                         {}, 
                        ]
               }
   }
]
```

I want to change `"Monthly Return"` to `"Weekly Return"` everywhere in the table column where it exists.

Thank you in advance!

I tried different approaches to Parse, read, OPENJSON, CROSS APPLY but could not make it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you mean sqlite ?

Comment: Yes, sqlite in DBeaver